# What is the default keyboard autorepeat rate?

Tags: keyboard, xset, autorepeat

I know I can change keyboard autorepeat settings with `xset r rate <delay> <rate>`.
Can anyone tell me the default values on Ubuntu? I've checked the man page and tried googling, to no avail.

Comment: `xset q` should display current settings.

Comment: This link might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/140255/how-to-override-the-new-limited-keyboard-repeat-rate-limit

Comment: @jimmij thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can display current settings with

```
xset -q
```

where among other useful information one can find:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on
  ...
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  ...
```

Delay is given in milliseconds and rate is the number of repeats per second.

Comment: Just a side note: both `xset q` and `xset -q` work, the later option (with dash) is more standard in unix world, but the former is given in xset manual.

Comment: Note that for many arguments (including `b` (bell), `dpms`, `fp` (font path), and `r` (repeat rate)), `xset` treats the presence or absence of `-` differently.  @jimmij is correct that both work the same for `q`, but in general, using `-` with `xset` can be surprising.